# how do you set the scrollbar position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div that has 7 panels in it but shows only 1 at a time when using the scrolling. My issue is how do I start at a certain distance within the div? I have looked up some solutions but can't seem to get them to work. Here is what I have so far:

JS

```
function olo() {
    el = document.getElementById("overlimo");
    el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";

    var targetXPos = 800;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollLeft: targetXPos
        }, 900);
    });
}
```

The HTML and CSS are long so unless you need to see them, I'll leave it out for now. The initial function olo() goes to an overlay. Since each link will have its own starting point, I need to know how to start at a certain position.

Say my initial div is 900px wide and the entire row within that div is 6300px. I need to set intervals for the remaining 6 panels when clicked: e.g. 900px in, 1800px in, 2700px in...etc.

Comment: So what is the problem? The code is not working? Or you don't know how to set the targetxpos for all the divs?

Comment: The code isn't working. I thought the var targetXPos would work but it is not starting within the div.

Comment: What does the HTML look like and the CSS for that bit? Maybe try changing: `scrollLeft: targetXPos+'px'`

Answer (score 2):

have you tried:

```
var targetXPos = $(el).position().left;
```

now if you're using a load of relative or absolute positioning, you may have to experiement between `.position()` and `.offset()`
also the code should probably be inside of the `doc.ready`

Answer (score 1):

What about just using scrollLeft on the body instead of via animate?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').scrollLeft(targetXPos);
});
```

[From the API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/)

Comment: the element is hidden so .scrollLeft won't work I don't think

Comment: Ah - yes, correct.  If hidden, won't work.  Is there a way to achieve your desired effect without hiding the element as the scroll position is set?